# Problema para desplegar servidor GLPI

Tags: composer

Tengo un problema a la hora de instalar el servidor GLPI a traves de xampp, tengo descargado el composer y la version de PHP 8.1.1 cuando ejecuto en el navegador me responde el aviso:

> Application dependencies are not up to date. Run "php bin/console
> dependencies install" in the glpi tree to fix this.

y una vez que con la consola ejecuto el comando con la consola colocada en la carpeta de glpip me responde:

> "composer" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa
> o archivo por lotes ejecutable

.
¿Alguna solución para poder finalizar la instalación?

Comment: el composer no lo has instalado globalmente tendrias que ubicarlo para poder ejecutarlo anteponiendo su ubicacion...

Comment: cuando tu pregunta en el sitio dice sugerencia, opciones, ideas etc... suelen cerrarte las preguntas por estar basadas en opiniones o faltar algo de ejemplo... trata de evitarlo

Comment: tambien seria bueno que agregaras los comandos que vas ejecutando... a lo mejor puede estar hay el error de sintaxis.